# Google results for my site are showing the title of a hidden modal element instead of my meta description

Tags: seo

I have a site that features a listing of companies. Every company has its own page. Every page has its own meta description. There is no `nofollow` or `noindex` tag or anything like that.

Yet, instead of the meta description, Google chooses to show the title of an insignificant modal element on the page. This is true for most results from the site. Maybe 10% of results show the meta description correctly.

This behavior is so seemingly random that I have no idea how to help the situation. There is a big `H1` title on the page, so if Google is ignoring the meta description, I would expect it to pick that.

The modal is hidden and it's not even the first modal when you look at the HTML source of the page.

Any suggestions?